# Is The Dirac Measure a weak derivative of a function?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

My precise question,: Is there any measurable function $\omega:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that for every compactly supported smooth function $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R),$
$$ \int_\mathbb R \phi(x) \omega(x) dx = \int_\mathbb R \phi(x) \,\delta(dx):= \phi(0).$$

In other words this might help to show that the weak derivative of the Heaviside function does not exist. Heaviside is defined as follows
$$ H(x) = 1 ~~~\text{if}~~~ x>0~~~ \text{and} ~~~0 ~~~\text{elsewhere} $$

Comment: In a word, no..

Comment: Such a measure is not continuous w.r.t Lebesgue measure, and so I direct you to @LordSharktheUnknown's answer.

Comment: please which answer are you talking about I can't find it out

Comment: I would like to see a clear proof of that statement. Clearly why does the equality $$\int_\mathbb R \phi \omega dx  = \phi(0).$$ is not true ?

Answer (score 5):

The first title of the post contained a question whether or not a Dirac measure is absolutely continuous wrt. the Lebesgue measure. I addressed this question, which is now, after the title change, inactual.

Concerning the question given in the title of the post, the Lebesgue measure of a singleton $\{x\}$ is zero, while its Dirac measure $\delta_x$ is $1$. That is why Dirac measure is not absolutely continuous wrt. the Lebesgue measure.

Comment: You are right but this does not answer my question I presume. Why does the equality in the statement can not holds true?

Comment: So, why did you give such a title? I have explicitly written that I address the question of a title.

Comment: I fixed it now it should be fine

Comment: Then I added an introductory sentence in my answer.